# Benchmark for memory usage by android app

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, benchmarking

I am building a fitnessapp which will focus on running. I just want to know is there any benchmark for android apps in terms of memory usage, CPU tune, RAM usage and network track so that i can compare the performance of my app to the benchmark and optimize it with respect to that.

Comment: yes you can check it through [google analytics](https://www.google.co.in/analytics/#/mobile-apps)

Comment: Does it also tell about the global benchmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to optimize your app, you can use Android Studio Monitor

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html

Memory usage and performance differs device to device. Do not take Other apps as a reference. It can be misleading. Optimize your app performance and memory usage as possible you can.